# docker container port forwarding behavior for `run` command (for websockets)

Tags: python, docker, websocket

I am running an ipython notebook server inside a docker container. Running code inside the notebook from the browser works over websockets, which have to connect from outside the container (a browser) to the tornado server running inside.

I noticed that when I start the notebook server directly with a `docker run` command

```
$ docker run -p 9000:9000 username/image ipython notebook --port=9000 --ip="*"
```

I cannot get a connection (the ipython notebook kernel connection times out). When I start a shell in the docker container with and the run the same command inside the container, the connection works perfectly:

```
$ docker run -it -p 9000:9000 username/image /bin/bash
$ ipython notebook --port=9000 --ip="*"  # inside docker image
```

In both cases, the ipython server log contains entries like

```
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:39946
```

for the websocket connections.

This makes it harder to script and autorun the container. What can I do to get the same behavior as in the second case direclty from `run`ning the image?

Comment: man docker-run and look for the -d option

Comment: @c4f4t0r -- I tried that, but it only detaches the container, the problem is the same in that case. I also tried `--privileged` to no avail.

Comment: have you tried: `docker run -p 9000:9000 username/image /bin/bash -c 'ipython notebook --port=9000 --ip="*"'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your `ipython` command requires to be run in bash - you should check the `ENTRYPOINT` of your Dockerfile, running `ipython` directly is not working for you.

Pass /bin/bash to the docker run command as so to test:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 username/image /bin/bash -c 'ipython notebook --port=9000 --ip="*"'
```